# Mobaxterm: Ctrl key seems locked

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I use mobaxterm to connect from windows to a vncserver session on linux.

I works fine for some time, but then `Ctrl` key seems to be locked.
Thus normal typing become impossible, e.g. typing `q` sends instead `Ctrl-q`.
(After reconnecting to the same session, it works a again, for a while).

Is there a fix to unlock `Ctrl` or even prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I found that pressing the Ctrl+Alt+Del button [image]
with the mouse stops locking the `ctrl` key.

Then one has to cancel the request to exit the session. This is at least more convenient than making a reconnection to the vnc session.

Comment: I have not found this to be case

Comment: @Pureferret Do you mean the problem does not occur in your case or the hack does not work for you?